# Como agregar un datapicker de bootstrap en angular correctamente?

Tags: angular, bootstrap, calendar, d

Empiezo apenas en angular y estoy realizando pruebas para usar un datapicker de bootstrap en mi proyecto angular. Ejecute el comando:
npm install bootstrap --save

y posterior agregue la siguiente linea en el archivo **angular.json**

```html
"styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
```

después ejecute el comando: **npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap**
y en el archivo **app.module.ts** importe los componentes: **NgbModule y FormsModule**

en mi **app.html** tengo lo siguiente

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

y en el archivo **app.component.ts**

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-datapicker';
  model: any;
}
```

y el resultado sale de la siguiente manera, el cual no me gusta, ya que no me puedo desplazar a los otros meses y no sale el icono del calendario, como lo puedo cambiar para que se vea bien y moderno?
que me esta faltando agregar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que la parte de "cómo hago para que se vea bien y moderno" puede considerarse como basado en opiniones, ya que es meramente estético y todos podrían tener un punto de vista diferente.